# Macro needed to convert row to sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm searching for a macro to take an excel file of several rows and split the sheet's rows up into sheets of any amount of rows we desire per-sheet, including the original rows, which should also be copied to each sheet. 
In simple if i have a file with row

```
1
2
3
```

then that macro split the rows make a sheet with .csv file like these so we get a 3 file form above

```
file1   file2   file3
  1         1       1
            2       2
                    3
```

i hope you get the point
i searched for it but only able to find

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitWorkbooksByNrows()
'Jerry Beaucaire,  2/28/2012
'Split all data sheets in a folder by a variable number or rows per sheet, optional titles
'assumes only one worksheet of data per workbook
Dim N As Long, rw As Long, LR As Long, Cnt As Long, Cols As String, Titles As Boolean
Dim srcPATH As String, destPATH As String, fNAME As String, wbDATA As Workbook, titleRNG As Range

srcPATH = "C:\Path\To\Source\Files\"            'remember the final \ in this string
destPATH = "C:\Path\To\Save\NewFiles\"          'remember the final \ in this string
                                                'determine how many rows per sheet to create
    N = Application.InputBox("How many rows per sheet?", "N-Rows", 50, Type:=1)
    If N = 0 Then Exit Sub                      'exit if user clicks CANCEL
                                                'Examples of usable ranges:  A:A    A:Z   C:E   F:F
    Cols = Application.InputBox("Enter the Range of columns to copy", "Columns", "A:Z", Type:=2)
    If Cols = "False" Then Exit Sub             'exit if user clicks CANCEL
                                                'prompt to repeat row1 titles on each created sheet
    If MsgBox("Include the title row1 on each new sheet?", vbYesNo, _
                "Titles?") = vbYes Then Titles = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False          'speed up macro execution
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False           'turn off system alert messages, use default answers
    fNAME = Dir(srcPATH & "*.xlsx")             'get first filename from srcPATH

    Do While Len(fNAME) > 0                     'exit loop when no more files found
        Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open(srcPATH & fNAME)        'open found file
        With ActiveSheet
            LR = Intersect(.Range(Cols), .UsedRange).Rows.Count             'how many rows of data?
            If Titles Then Set titleRNG = Intersect(.Range(Cols), .Rows(1)) 'set title range, opt.
            For rw = 1 + ---Titles To LR Step N 'loop in groups of N rows
                Cnt = Cnt + 1                   'increment the sheet creation counter
                Sheets.Add                      'create the new sheet
                If Titles Then titleRNG.Copy Range("A1")    'optionally add the titles
                                                'copy N rows of data to new sheet
                Intersect(.Range("A" & rw).Resize(N).EntireRow, .Range(Cols)).Copy Range("A1").Offset(Titles)
                ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit     'cleanup
                ActiveSheet.Move                'move created sheet to new workbook
                                                'save with incremented filename in the destPATH
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs destPATH & "Datafile_" & Format(Cnt, "00000") & ".xlsx", xlNormal
                ActiveWorkbook.Close False      'close the created workbook
            Next rw                             'repeat with next set of rows
        End With
        wbDATA.Close False                      'close source data workbook

        fNAME = Dir                             'get next filename from the srcPATH
    Loop                                        'repeat for each found file

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True           'return to normal speed
    MsgBox "A total of " & Cnt & " data files were created."        'report
End Sub
```

Reference https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/parse-functions/rows
What this macro is doing

```
if we have these rows
    1
    2
    3
```

Macro doing this

```
file1   file2   file3
  1         2       3
```

The code which is provided do exactly what i wanted but only if the macro can add the rows to. Like this.

```
file1   file2   file3
  1         1       1
            2       2
                    3
```

Comment: Try using the macro recorder to get a general idea of the code needed. As of right now it's hard to understand what you need and you don't seem to have tried to write any code...

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Take some time, and edit your question (and comment above) into understandable English. I fear you will simply be closed off otherwise.

Comment: Ok have added more details for more understanding of the question. I think it will be clear now what i am asking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help get you started. You'll need to put your own range references and filepaths etc.

```
Sub SplitAndSave()
    Dim rows As Long, rw As Long, myFolder As String, ws As Worksheet

    rows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").rows.Count
    myFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\MyFolder\"
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    For rw = 1 To rows
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
        Range("A1:A" & rw).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A1")
        ws.SaveAs myFolder & "file" & rw & ".csv", xlCSV
    Next rw
End Sub
```

This will split your data in `Range(A1:A10)` in to ten separate `.csv` files and place them in a folder called `MyFolder` on the desktop.

Comment: Macro worked You rock one thing more if we have 5 columns Than how we will do it.

Comment: For five columns change to `Range("A1:E" & rw).Copy...`